# An error while downloading manually via VSIX

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

im trying to install vscode extension for my project, but An error appears. After manual download via vsix appears UnhandledException. I've tried some tutorials on youtube and tackoverflow, but it doesn't work

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

I try to solve it with searching some tutorials on youtube and stackoverflow, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

The shown extension is an extension pack, where the only included extension is the `Debugger for Unity`.
If you select it, you will see this screen:

[image]

So, this extension is deprecated, last release was in 2020. You may not get this to work unless you fork it on Github and fix it yourself.

Or have a look if someone else already did, like this one, which provides a more recent version of this Unity debugger:

[image]